# Get params and remove one of them from url

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have a problem with an url.
I wanna get all params from url and remove one of them (the bigger param)

For example, I have this url:

```
localhost/abc/etc/zzz.htmll?A=1+A_2+A_3+A&B=1+B_2+B
```

I want to get all params, so I use:

```
$params =  $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

And I want to remove the bigger param, so it is `A` because I have `1+A_2+A_3+A` and `B` only has `1+B_2+B`. I use:

```
$paramu[$i] = explode('_', $param)
```

To get `1+A`, `2+A`, `3+A` and `1+B`, `2+B`

But how can I remove the `A` from the url, so I want that the url becomes:

```
localhost/abc/etc/zzz.htmll?B=1+B_2+B
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: did you used str_replace()?

Comment: maybe it can work, i will try

Comment: but the problem is how can i get the bigger param?

Comment: i am not understanding what is bigger param?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way will be to just send a new request, with the small  param only - that will change the url and do the job you need.

As to checking which one is bigger - after you used "explode", just check for the size of each array you recived (you get 2 arrays - one for "A" and one for "B")